# How do you save a single space (" ") in a field in a django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My model definition looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    tag_separator = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
```

The `tag_separator` is a single character, and it can be a single space: `" "`.
I need to select `null=True` in order to get it to work, but when I POST data through my REST API, it saves the `tag_separator` as an empty string: `"tag_separator": ""`.

Is there a simple way to stop Django from assuming that my single space string is an empty string?

I am using: `Django==1.11` and `djangorestframework==3.7.7`

Answer (score 1):

On your Serializer, pass in [`trim_whitespace=False`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) into your `CharField`. ie:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag_separator = serializers.CharField(trim_whitespace=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Similarly, when you use django's forms, use [`strip=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.strip):

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tag_separator = forms.CharField(strip=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work on django 1.11, which I am stuck with because I am on Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
class NonStrippingCharField(models.CharField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['strip'] = False
        return super(NonStrippingCharField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

Then in my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    tag_separator = NonStrippingCharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
```